# Mastering Bitcoin: Where is the checksum coming from when running bx base58check-decode?

Tags: checksum

For example, if I run `bx base58check-decode` with the base58 encoded private key of `Kxj5ejwPg2s2ejZHW7N1zAydD4fkmFi9j19QRmgeVK9mXL3wFMmp` from this [example](https://royalforkblog.github.io/2014/08/11/graphical-address-generator/#hello), I get the following:

`{
    checksum 2274467570
    payload 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b982401
    version 128
}`

The payload, as well as the version, make sense to me; however, if I convert the checksum to a hex, it doesn't match the checksum of F29E9187 that I'm expecting, i.e., I understand how to form it per this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51970/how-to-generate-a-bitcoin-private-key-checksum). But I don't understand how 2274467570 and F29E9187 are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decimal to hex, and then reversed ordering:

```
$ echo "obase=16;2274467570" | bc
87919EF2
```

reversed:
87 91 9E F2 -> F2 9E 91 87